# Javascript Google Chrome Extension, Looking For Domain Name, Not APP ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I tried to get the domain name using `alert(document.domain);` But i'm not getting the right domain when I have the app installed on my chrome extension tool bar and test it out in a site,

I keep getting "hiecjmnbal...(long value)" which I believe represents my google app's id.

I have added this in the manifest too

```
  "content_scripts": [
        {
        "js": ["inject.js"]

        }
  ],
```

`alert(document.domain);` is the only line of text inside `inject.js`.

I've also used `window.top.location` which shows the chrome extension url of: `chrome-extension://hiecjmnbal...(long value)/popup.html`

And I've incorporated this `<script type="text/javascript" src="inject.js"> </script>` into the main html file after `popup.js`

Any thoughts on why I'm not getting the correct domain url and only getting google chrome's extension URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
alert(location.href);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it when I get back to my desk. Can I ask why the others don't work and this one might?

Comment: @andrewliu I think it might be because document.domian: Gets/sets the domain portion of the origin of the **current document**. See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.domain

Comment: I just tried inserting that code instead, still gives me same results! :( ahhhh

Comment: @andrewliu hmm, sorry for the silly question, but you are sure that is the code you are loading? did you refresh the plugin?

Comment: @andrewliu also, you're sure it's a content script right? Sorry for the seemingly stupid question but location.href should work, it works just fine in my extension: https://github.com/trufa/Remember-Last-Read-Tweet/blob/master/script.js#L5

Comment: Weird, so I just discovered something. I did make sure that I've refreshed my code. I added an alert just to make sure that its been updated. So I added `"matches": ["<all_urls>"],` above `"js": ["inject.js"]` within `"content_scripts"` and whenever I go to a new page, it'll alert the right URL automatically, but when I click on the extension icon at the corner of the browser, it outputs the chrome extension url?

Comment: @andrewliu It was probably because you couldn't access any other URL, so the script was limited to it's context.